# CPU usage for Android app on ADB Shell and Trace files are dfifferent

Tags: android, adb, cpu-usage

The ADB shell shows  98 % CPU usage, while through Trace file I can see it only 45%. 
Why is this difference? And which one is reliable way for finding the CPU usage for my app; ADB Shell or Trace file?

Thanks and regards,

Heshsham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the **trace file is just related to your application**.. and it gives the amount of cpu usage for your application in particular.. but **adb shell gives the cpu usage of all applications** running at that instance.. so trace file value is the one which you should consider..for your application

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I have JNI part having some C source file in my application. Can you please tell me that time(CPU Time) showing in trace file is the total time taken by my whole application or only of the Android part(not JNI)??

Comment: Thank you for Reply... Is there any way to trace the JNI part(CPU time taken by C functions). Because I want to know which function is taking how much CPU Time.